# python cannot find a module that was installed with sudo pip3 install

Tags: python, pip

I installed a python library using `sudo pip3 install metis`. But when I run a python program without `sudo` that requires the library it says that the module is not found.

It says that `metis` is located in `Requirement already satisfied: metis in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.2a4)`

How do I configure python to look in this directory?

Comment: Is the site-packages folder in your system path?

Comment: why are you using `sudo` for `pip3 install`? just perform a normal `pip3 install`

Comment: @wpercy `pip3 install metis --user`
Collecting metis
Installing collected packages: metis
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/tom/.local/lib/python3.6'
Check the permissions.

Comment: @wpercy I tried without sudo and I denied, how do I change permissions? thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using a `virtualenv` [LINK](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: With regards to the `pip3 install metis --user` giving you Errno 13, that might be because of a previous `sudo pip` call that installed in the `/home/tom/.local/` directory. Try the following command: `sudo chown -R tom /home/tom/.local`, and re-run `pip3 install metis --user` without sudo.

Comment: @jhill515 thanks you very much that worked!